# Do goblins prioritize town hall over defences

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans since townhalls provide 1k gold and 1k elixir upon destruction does that mean it is categorised as a resource? and if so will that mean that goblins take priority of townhall over defences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They'll prioritize ANY resource (Gold, Elixir, Dark Elixir) before going on the the Town Hall, then to the defenses.

Comment: +1 correct.  They will prioritize the closest resource not surrounded by walls.

Comment: This... isn't matching with my recent experience. My goblins seem to ignore the Town Hall unless all collectors/storage buildings are destroyed and it's the closest un-destroyed building near them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. Giants are mostly the defense breakers. It does count as a resource, but you should place goblins last when you attack, unless you have a ton of them. The defenses destroy goblins quickly, in case you wanted to know. Hope I could help! ;)